apt install ubuntu-desktop is very slow
I'm running "apt install ubuntu-desktop" from server install of 24.04. It downloads everything very quickly, but when setting up packages it becomes very very slow. It takes more that an hour+ to complete. I also had this problem with 23.x versions but not with 22.04. Also connecting to this host via ssh while installation is running takes unusually long time, yet top does not show anything unusual. Eventually installation completes and everything is fine. What could be going on?

What's your network connection? What's on the other end? Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

As I indicated in my question this is not a problem with slow download. All packages get downloaded very quickly from Ubuntu repos. Slow down happens when packages are being setup which does not involve network. I'm not sure what is "the other end".

Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].
